# Difficulty in proving a result based on linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to solve following exercise problem from a book.

Let $V$ be a nonzero finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Let $T: V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^n=0$ but $T^{n-1}\neq 0$ for some natural number $n>1$. I have to prove that there exists a nonzero vector $v\in V$ such that $\{v, T(v), T^2(v), \ldots, T^{n-1}(v)\}$ is linearly independent over filed $F$.

I try to prove by method of contradiction. Suppose  that $T^n=0$ but $T^{n-1}\neq 0$ holds but there doesn't exist nonzero vector $v\in V$ such that $A =\{v, T(v), T^2(v), \ldots, T^{n-1}(v)\}$ is linearly independent over filed $F$. So, vectors in $A$ must be linearly dependent. So,  the linear combination $a_1v +a_2T(v)+a_3T^2(v)+ \ldots +T^{n-1}(v)=0$ for some nonzero $a_i\in F$.

After, this step I am not able to proceed. Is there any other approach to solve this problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you use the Jordan form?

Comment: @copper.hat Dear sir I have not been introduced jordan form?

Comment: Follow @user24142's hint below to show that $v,Tv,...,T^{n-1}v$  are linearly independent directly.

Comment: @copper.hat I am trying sir. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Start with the assumption that $v$ is such that $T^n v = 0$ and $T^{n-1} v \neq 0$. Now, make you assumption, using $v$. What happens if we apply $T$ to both sides of the equation? What if we apply it again? Is there a number of applications that lets you prove your result?

Comment: I am trying and will let you know. Thanks a lot for the hint.